# tkFileDialog for non existents files

Tags: python-2.7, file, tkinter

At his start, my program asks to open a file or to create a new one.
If the file does not exist or the user wants to create a new one, he should have to manage this event in the same File Dialog.

TkFileDialog has two modes: save to a file (existing or not) and open an existing file.

Is there a way to allow that, if the user inserts a non-existent file, tkFileDialog creates the file without the "file not found" error?

Comment: No, but you could use `asksaveasfilename()` and use the returned name to check if it exists and create it if not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as Novel said, the answer to your question is no. 
But there is a way override it using the following code :

```
        import os
        os.chdir(path_to_file_dir)
        f = open(how_you_wanna_call_it, 'rb')
```

If there will be no existing file on the path you've provided, it will create one (empty of course), then you can use it with the tkFileDialog.
Make sure you write the file extension as well in the name(how_you_wanna_call_it).

For example :

```
import os
os.chdir("C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\")
f = open("a.py",'rb')
```

will create a.py in "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\". (if there is no a.py).

Hopefully this will help you, 
Yahli.